# pytorch.to(device="cuda") leads to killed process in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/python-39:1-48
USER root

....

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock start-singleuser.sh setup-volume.sh jupyter_notebook_config.py ${PY_PKG_DIR}/
COPY config/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
COPY config/core-site.xml /etc/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
COPY config/hdfs-site.xml /etc/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.1/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
COPY content/root/ 

# System Setup
RUN DIST=$(. /etc/os-release; echo $ID$VERSION_ID)\
 && dnf -y --enablerepo "ubi-8*" update --nobest\
 && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$DIST/libnvidia-container.repo |tee /etc/yum.repos.d/libnvidia-container.repo\
 && dnf -y --enablerepo "ubi-8*" install java-11-openjdk nvidia-container-toolkit nodejs nss_wrapper git\
 && dnf -y --enablerepo "ubi-8*" clean all\
 && dnf list installed

RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime\
 && echo "Europe/Berlin" > /etc/timezone\
 && python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade\
 && python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install poetry\
 && poetry config virtualenvs.create false\
 && cd ${PY_PKG_DIR}\
 && poetry install --no-dev -v

RUN keytool -import -alias ad_r8737 -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts -file /usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/R8737.pem -noprompt -storepass changeit

RUN chmod g+w /etc/krb5.conf\
 && mkdir -p /opt/app-root/src/.local\
 && chmod g+w /opt/app-root/src/.local

ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/opt/pip/pip.conf\
#    PIP_TARGET=${PACKAGE_DIR}\
    PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/jup/packages"\
    HOME=${WORKING_DIR}

RUN python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"


RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --target="/opt/app-root/lib/python3.9/site-packages"
RUN python3 -m pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113\
    && pip install jupyter --target="/opt/app-root/lib/python3.9/site-packages"

RUN python3 -m IPython kernel install --name "torch_cuda" --display-name "Kernel for development with GPUs"

# Gibt es einen Grund das anders zu machen?
RUN chmod -R 775 /opt/pip
RUN chmod -R 775 /proc/driver

EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/opt/app-root/src/app-pkg/start-singleuser.sh"]
```

The Container runs in a Kubernetes cluster and as soon as I try to use my GPU, the Python process instantly crashes:

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.rand(4).to(device="cuda")
Killed
(app-root)
```

I am not able to debug it, since there is no stacktrace or something, just a killed process with "killed". Does anyone know what might cause the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: `torch.rand(4).to(device="cuda:0")`?

Comment: or `torch.rand(4).cuda()`?

Comment: @trsvchn: The kernel instantly also dies with these commands.

Comment: did you install nvidia driver on the host machine? I think this is requirement